# EF Core: filter condition for nested collection (Func<>) as a variable

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

tl;dr;
I .Net6 I want to pass to dbcontext.Entities.Include(host => host.nestedeCollection.Where(element => )) func element =>  via a variable Func<ElementType, bool>. It works with Z.Entityframework.Extensions, but cannot convert it to EF Core.

Long story.
Consider the following model:

```
public class Attendance {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public decimal Rank { get; set; }
}

public class Student {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}

public class UniversityDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(student => student.Attendances)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId)
        ;
    }
}
```

I want to:

```
var students = db
    .Students
    .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(att => att.Rank < 3.0m))
    .ToList()
;
```

At the moment I am using Z.EntityFramework.Extensions .IncludeOptimized. Since Net5 there is an EF-native feature to perform the same task, and the code above just works fine for scenarios like above {{Where(att => att.Rank < 3.0m)}} . In real life I have quite a complex condition for .Where clause and I have to repeat it within multiple .Include and .ThenInclude statements when loading my data, and unfortunately global filters do not help in this case unless I totally refactor the app. What I did for Z.EntityFramework.Extensions is:

```
Func<Attendance, bool> func = attendance => attendance.Rank < 3.0m;
var students = db
    .Students
    .IncludeOptimized(student => student.Attendances.Where(func))
    .ToList()
;
```

It worked.

Now, I try the same with NET6 and latest available EF Core. All attempts fail:

```
        Func<Attendance, bool> func_x = attendance => true;
        Func<Attendance, bool> func_y = attendance => attendance.Rank < 3.0m;
        Expression<Func<Attendance, bool>> expr = att => att.Rank < 3.0m; 

        //*
        using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) {
            var students_x = db
                .Students
                .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(func_x))
                .ToList()
            ;
        }

        //**
        //using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) {
        //    var students_z = db
        //        .Students
        //        .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(x => func_x(x)))
        //        .ToList()
        //    ;
        //}
        
        //***
        //using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) {
        //    var students_y = db
        //        .Students
        //        .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(func_y))
        //        .ToList()
        //    ;
        //}

        //****
        //using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) {
        //    var students_z = db
        //        .Students
        //        .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(Func_z))
        //        .ToList()
        //    ;
        //}
        
        //*****
        //using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) {
        //    var students_expr = db
        //        .Students
        //        .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(expr))
        //        .ToList()
        //    ;
        //}
```

//* fails with

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance] Where[Attendance](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.TryConvertEnumerableToQueryable(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.NormalizeQueryableMethod(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor.NormalizeQueryableMethod(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at FuncInEFIncludeExample.Program.Main() in W:\Projects\FuncInEFInclude\FuncInEFIncludeExample\Program.cs:line 81
```

//** fails with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Attendance>()
    .Where(a => EF.Property<Guid?>(EntityShaperExpression: 
        FuncInEFIncludeExample.Student
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
        IsNullable: False
    , "Id") != null && object.Equals(
        objA: (object)EF.Property<Guid?>(EntityShaperExpression: 
            FuncInEFIncludeExample.Student
            ValueBufferExpression: 
                ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False
        , "Id"), 
        objB: (object)EF.Property<Guid?>(a, "StudentId")))
    .Where(a => Invoke(__func_x_0, a)
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSubquery(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IncludeExpression.VisitChildren(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at FuncInEFIncludeExample.Program.Main() in W:\Projects\FuncInEFInclude\FuncInEFIncludeExample\Program.cs:line 91
```

The rest are failing as //*, and the last one, //*****, as expected, does not even compile.

I tried further to play around with nested collections, making them IQueryable<>. Could not achieve what I want. I am especially confused by

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FuncInEFIncludeExample.Attendance]
```

Is there an invalid cast in the middle of Visitor pattern implementation (looking at stacktrace)?

Hence is my question.
Has anybody tried to achieve the same in EF Core? May be any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: So you were using  Z.EntityFramework.Extensions 's `IncludeOptimized`  to convert a `Func<,bool>` to an `Expression<Func<,bool>>`  which no longer works. That's not an EF Core problem. What's the *actual* expression? If the expression you used can't be translated to SQL, no extension would work

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? None of the queries you wrote would ever work except the one that accepts an `Expression` and as you said, `.Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(att => att.Rank < 3.0m))` works. If you want to pass expressions dynamically, check [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, with Z. I could do Func<A, bool> func = a => a.Rank; and then just supply func into .Where extension made by Z. Now the same-ish logic by EF-native does not work. And with Expression the issue is that .Where() takes Func<>, not Expression<>. Anyway, thanks for the link to LINQKit -- I'll check it tomorrow, but just thought it's possible to achieve without with EF-native filtering.

Comment: It never worked. Not before, not now. EF and EF Core deal with Expression not Func. Z.EntityFramework.Extensions is a third-party *paid, closed source* extension. What Z did was convert that Func to an Expression. Now Z fails to do this. Since you paid for this you can ask the vendor to solve the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, a) .Include works with .Where clause for a nested collection since EFCore in NET5. .Where accepts Func (because it is IEnumerable in model above)
b) Z.Entity does not fail now, it's still working. I just wanted to get rid of it in favour of (if available) EFCore-native feature.

Comment: No it doesn't accept a Func. You won't be able to understand what the problem was until you accept this. This isn't an opinion, it's fully documented and explained in several dozens of similar questions where people got the same error you did. All `IQueryable<T>` extensions accept expressions, not functions. It's only the `Enumerable<T>` extensions that accept `Func`. In LINQ-to-EF the EF provider takes the **expressions** and translates them to SQL. It always did. A `Func` can't be inspected, only executed.

Comment: If you still insist [check the Queryable.Where overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-6.0). Both accept `Expression`, not `Func`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, (this is FW, note core, but interface did not change) https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs ;  I clearly see public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) . I also tried to replace IEnumerable to IQueryable (with some extra steps) -- no luck.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong file. Those extensions are for IEnumerable<T>, not IQueryable<T>. Those work only on the IEnumerables produced *after* executiong a LINQ query, or to in-memory collections that implement IEnumerable<>. You can't "replace IEnumerable to IQueryable" - your queries are already `IQueryable`s. When you pass a function to that `Where` you're actually creating an *expression* that contains a function call. The EF Core LINQ provider sees only that, and doesn't know what to do with the opaque function call.

Comment: When you use `.Where(att => att.Rank < 3.0m)` on the other hand, you're creating a composite expression: a binary comparison whose right side is a constant and left is a property access. LINQ knows how to translate all of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want query translation, you have to deal only with `Expression`, just `Func` is not tranaslateble to the SQL. Good news, that you do not need `Z.EntityFramework`, bad news that EF Core still will not translate your query.

You neeed ligthweigh library [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring DbContextOptions:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then you can use your expression via `Invoke` extension:

```cs
Expression<Func<Attendance, bool>> func_x = attendance => true;
Expression<Func<Attendance, bool>> func_y = attendance => attendance.Rank < 3.0m;
Expression<Func<Attendance, bool>> expr = att => att.Rank < 3.0m; 

using (var db = new UniversityDbContext(connString)) 
{
    var students_x = db
        .Students
        .Include(student => student.Attendances.Where(x => func_x.Invoke(x)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks, will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Svyatoslav, Panagiotos -- thanks. I confirm LINQKit solves the issue (albeit I wanted to achieve it w/o 3rd-party library).

Comment: Possible for sure, but do you have time to make your injection into EF Core services and correct expression tree?

Comment: @rezdm but .... you used a third-party extension already. What you want to do *never* worked with EF.

Comment: @rezdm in fact, given that Z.EntityFramework.Extensions is a *paid closed source product*, why do you even post a question here? Shouldn't you contact the vendor?

Answer (score -1):

As suggested, LINQKit is the answer so far.
Thanks.

Comment: Delete this message and mark answer as an answered.

Comment: If an answer helped you, mark it. Don't post another answer